# El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos. Nombre del parámetro Index. [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, bucle-for, index

Estoy tratando de remover un carácter de una cadena, lo remueve con **'remove'**
pero en lugar de que el ciclo **for** llegue hasta la nueva longitud de la cadena, continua a su longitud previa y arroja el error de la pregunta. *(VB)*

**Ejem:**

Si la longitud previa era de 10
menos el carácter removido 9
el ciclo continuará hasta la posición 10

**El código es el siguiente:**

```
          For i = 0 To name.Length  - e
                       
             If Not Char.IsLetter(name, i) And Not name.Substring(i, 1) = " " Then
                           

                            errores &= insured.Nombre.Substring(i, 1) & ", "
                           
                             name = name.Remove(i, 1) 
                             e = e + 1
          Next
```